# WPF Combobox binding selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have the following problem. I have this Models:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
        
    }

    public string ID { get; }
    public string Name { get ; set; }
    public B objectB { get; set; }

}

public class B
{
    public B(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public string ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> ListOne = new ObservableCollection<A>();
    public ObservableCollection<B> ListTwo = new ObservableCollection<B>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        B objectB = new B("1");
        objectB.Name = "ObjectB";

        B listElement2 = new B("2");
        listElement2.Name = "ListElement2";

        ListTwo.Add(objectB);
        ListTwo.Add(listElement2);

        A objectA = new A("A1");
        objectA.Name = "objectA1";
        objectA.objectB = objectB;

        ListOne.Add(objectA);
    }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOne}" Name="MyListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=DataContext.ListTwo}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding objectB}"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

`Class A` contains a object ob `Class B`.
My `ViewModel` contains two lists. One list (ListOne) of class A objects and second list (ListTwo) contains objects of class B.

Now I want to bind `listTwo` to `combobox` which is embedded into a `listbox`. The `listbox` displays all objects in the `listOne` of the viewmodels.
If I change the selection of `combobox` I want to update the property objectB of the selected item of listbox. I also want that the `combobox` select the value of objectB during initialization.

Please note: I simplified the model and the viewmodel to focus on the problem. NotifyProperties and so on works. I am interested in the binding of the combobox.

I have no idea to do this. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you post your xaml?

Comment: I added the xaml

Comment: And most definitely the viewModel too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListB}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedB}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="100"
/>
```

Also, you may add the following code in your ViewModel :

```
private ObservableCollection<B> listB = new ObservableCollection<B>();
public ObservableCollection<B> ListB
{
    get { return this.listB; }
    set { this.listB = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ListB"); }
}

private B selectedB;
public B SelectedB
{
    get { return this.selectedB; }
    set { this.selectedB = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedB"); }
}
ViewModel()
{
    //Fill your ListB with all possible values
    this.SelectedB=ListB.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==A.ObjectB.ID)
}
```

Then your classes may be INotifyPropertyChanged :

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public long ID=-1;
    private string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    private B objectB;
    public B ObjectB
    {
        get{return this.objectB;}
        set
        {
            this.objectB=value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

}
```

Iam almost sure you could also replace SelectedB by A.ObjectB for binding, but would need to make some tests to check it. Advantage (or inconvenient it depends), is that if you Bind on A.ObjectB, the changes will be effective as soon as you change the selected item in ComboBox. Making so you can change your ComboBox value without modifying directly your A object, then on closing Window, you can ask to save or not, and if yes, just do A.ObjectB=SelectedB.

Comment: Hi Siegfried.V thanks for your post. 
But the ItemsSource of my Combobox is not ListOne. 
ListOne contains in the Property 'objectB' of each list element which item I want to select in the combobox which have the ListTwo as source. 
So the Property 'objectB' is my bridge between the two lists.

Comment: ah I see, didn't notice sorry, I edit now the answer

Comment: In fact the problem is not only from the XAML, but also your classes are not correct, sis I understand good that your class A, has a list of <B> objects inside?

Comment: How should I design my classes then? 
What I want to achieve is the following:
I have a type A object which internally holds a type B object (Property ObjectB). 
In the view I display the object of type A and in the combo box I have a selection of objects of type B. The selected element of the combo box wants to store it in the property ObjectB. When I call the type A object in the view again I want the type B object I hold in the property ObjectB to be selected in the combo box. 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: @mannmawg so in your View, you display only one object A, then ComboBox corresponds to a list of objects , right? Excuse me for delay was on a job and didn't see time flying...